Maximal Ideal spaces in Noncommutative C*-algebra
In commutative C*-algebra the set of maximal ideals is in one-one correspondence with the set of multiplicative linear functionals. Is there such a correspondence in the noncommutative case?
Or rather a little weaker statement: Given a multiplicative linear functional on a noncommutative C*-algebra, can we find a maximal ideal which is kernel of the multiplicative linear functional?

What did you try? Please edit your post to share some thoughts about your question +
Your "weaker statement" is strangely worded. The kernel of a functional $f$ is determined by $f$.

Just take the kernel. It is going to be a maximal ideal. But note that not all maximal ideals arise this way. Say, the zero ideal in a simple $C^\ast$-algebra (that is not just $\mathbb{C}$), or $K(l^2)$ in $B(l^2)$.
